# Custom wrapper component with props and v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-select

I am using the `vue-select` library: https://github.com/desislavsd/vue-select  in my app.

Since I am using a lot of them I just want to make a separate wrapper component, but now my selects don't work. Vue somehow doesn't recognize the props. How can I make my `v-select` a separate reusable component that can accept it's normal props and worK?

This is my Select component:

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <v-select/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "Select",
}
</script>
```

And this is how I am using it:

```js
<Select as="role" placeholder="Assesor" v-model="value1" :from="roles"  :key="roles.role" />

export default {
  name: "Admin",
  components: {
    Header,
    Select
  },
  data() {
    return {
      value1: [],
      selected: {
       role: ''
      },
      roles: [
        { role: "Assesors" },
        { role: "Finance" },
        { role: "Sales" }
      ]
    };
  }
};
```

Comment: you're not passing any props

Comment: shouldn't they be available from the library?

Comment: What is `from`?  I don't see that prop in the API

Comment: Here it is https://jsfiddle.net/desislavsd/es2n6py0/

Comment: If I just use   <v-select  as="role" placeholder="Assesor"   v-model="value1" :from="roles" :key="roles.role" />  it works, but when I try via a component it does not

Comment: This is an uncommon library, not the more popular [vue-select](https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-select).  What is `selected` doing?  It's not used anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

This is more complex than it seems.  You expect the props passed to the custom component to be applied to the inner `v-select` but Vue doesn't know that.  Someone else might expect them to go on the `<div>`.

#### `v-bind="$attrs"`

Props are not automatically passed to a child element.  To do that, you need:

```html
<v-select v-bind="$attrs" />
```

#### `v-model`

Now the props are applied to the element you choose.  But since `v-model` is a special prop from the parent with hidden functionality, it's not passed properly without some extra preparation.  You'll have to code a `v-model` directly on the child:

```html
<v-select v-bind="$attrs" v-model="model" />
```

#### Computed setter

The parent's `v-model` passes down a `value` prop.  Create a computed setter in the custom element (I'm calling it `model`) to use with the child's `v-model`:

```js
computed: {
  model: {
    get() { return this.$attrs.value },
    set(val) { this.$emit('input', val) }
  }
}
```

Here is the [updated demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/rhdusenz/) with a custom wrapper component using `selected` and `as="role::role"`